# Shopify Liquid If Statement for Shop Name

Tags: if-statement, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I have my brand name or shop name added to all my URL's via the following statement which is found in the theme.liquid file. I want to exclude all pages that are blogs or articles. This would mean no shop name on those URL's, which is this pipe and code.

```
&#124; {{ shop.name }}
```

**Original Code**

```
  {%- capture seo_title -%}
    {%- if template == 'search' and search.performed == true -%}
      {{ 'general.search.heading' | t: count: search.results_count }}: {{ 'general.search.results_with_count' | t: terms: search.terms, count: search.results_count }}
    {%- else -%}
      {{ page_title }}
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- if current_tags -%}
      {%- assign meta_tags = current_tags | join: ', ' -%} &ndash; {{ 'general.meta.tags' | t: tags: meta_tags -}}
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- if current_page != 1 -%}
      &ndash; {{ 'general.meta.page' | t: page: current_page }}
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- assign escaped_page_title = page_title | escape -%}
    {%- unless escaped_page_title contains shop.name -%}
      &#124; {{ shop.name }}
    {%- endunless -%}
  {%- endcapture -%}
    <title>{{ seo_title | strip }}</title>
```

I have been trying to place another if statement around the following but I have had no luck yet.

```
    {%- assign escaped_page_title = page_title | escape -%}
    {%- unless escaped_page_title contains shop.name -%}
      &#124; {{ shop.name }}
    {%- endunless -%}
```

This is the code that I have tried, is there a better way to do this as I can't quite get it to work.

**Attempted Code**

```
  {%- capture seo_title -%}
    {%- if template == 'search' and search.performed == true -%}
      {{ 'general.search.heading' | t: count: search.results_count }}: {{ 'general.search.results_with_count' | t: terms: search.terms, count: search.results_count }}
    {%- else -%}
      {{ page_title }}
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- if current_tags -%}
      {%- assign meta_tags = current_tags | join: ', ' -%} &ndash; {{ 'general.meta.tags' | t: tags: meta_tags -}}
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- if current_page != 1 -%}
      &ndash; {{ 'general.meta.page' | t: page: current_page }}
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- if (template == "blog" or template == "article") and current_tags contains '_NOINDEX' -%}
    {%- assign escaped_page_title = page_title | escape -%}
    {%- unless escaped_page_title contains shop.name -%}
    {%- endunless -%}
    {%- else -%}
    {%- assign escaped_page_title = page_title | escape -%}
    {%- unless escaped_page_title contains shop.name -%}
      &#124; {{ shop.name }}
    {%- endunless -%}
   {%- endif -%}
  {%- endcapture -%}
    <title>{{ seo_title | strip }}</title>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the following:

```
 {%- unless escaped_page_title contains shop.name or template == 'blog' or template == 'article' -%}
   &#124; {{ shop.name }}
 {%- endunless -%}
```

You were close, but you cannot use parentheses to group Liquid condition operators.

Comment: Thank you. It appears I was making it much harder than it had to be. I appreciate the help.